# Transfer ASP.NET session to other ASP.NET solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, response.redirect

I got a 2 ASP.NET solution. The first one is called HomePage and the other Main. I'm using IIS 7.5. At the root of IIS, I got 2 folders with the same name (HomePage and Main). Each solution is in their own folder.

I'm trying to transfer a session from HomePage to Main.

Main project (file ASPNETToASPNET.aspx)

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string queryString = String.Empty;
    string destPage = Request.Form["destpage"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

HomePage.aspx

```
private void Redirect_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.website.com/Main/Pages/ASPNETToASPNET.aspx?destpage=" + e.CommandArgument + "&SessionNoClient=" + Session["SessionNoClient"], false);
    Response.Redirect("./Main/Pages/ASPNETToASPNET.aspx?destpage=" + e.CommandArgument + "&SessionNoClient=" + Session["SessionNoClient"], false);
}
```

When using the first redirect, I reach the appropriate file, but I got an error at line

```
string destPage = Request.Form["destpage"].ToString();
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When using the other redirect, I'm not able to find a way to reach the appropriate file.

As mentioned, both solutions are on same server and use the same domain.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string destPage = Request.QueryString["destpage"];
```

1. This is not a transfer of session, you're just passing query parameters.
2. `Request.Form` collection contains POST values. For query string parameters (GET) use `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Params`, the last one searches your value in  `QueryString`, `Form`, `Cookies`, and `ServerVariables`.